# Положение элементов при разных разрешениях экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Если размер экрана ≥ 992px, то две верхних строки идут в ряд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда меньше, то накладываются одна на другую.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А знаю, что есть классы типа col-xs-12, col-md-6, col-lg-5 и т.д. Я их пока не очень понимаю.
Что конкретно нужно сделать, чтобы строки не накладывались другу на друга при ширине < 992px?
Не давайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на getbootsrap.com

Answer (score 1):

Работа с бутстрапом подразумевает, что все элементы верстаются в "сетку". Сетка - это скажем так область экрана, мысленно разбитая на 12 вертикальных столбцов.

Возьмем для примера такую структуру:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для ширины экрана (≥1200px) ширина `container` будет равна 1170px, для (≥992px) - 970px, для (≥768px) - 750px. Я всё же дам ссылку на [Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). `row`- это строка, в которую будут набиваться блоки. А в строке в моём примере один блок, который занимает всю ширину `container` на широких экранах, на средних экранах - половину ширины, на малых экранах - 1/6 часть (2 колонки из 12).

В вашем случае предполагаю, что элементы формы сверстаны не в сетке бутстрап (без указания, сколько колонок сетки должен занимать каждый элемент). Должно быть что-то в этом роде:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

А чтобы понять почему именно так, я пожалуй дам ссылку еще раз на [Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

И еще можно поиграться с онлайн-конструктором и посмотреть, как верстают другие вот тут http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @Ravdan если ответ решил вашу проблему, принято его "принимать" - зеленая птичка под стрелками слева. Тогда другие пользователи будут знать, что вопрос решен.

Comment: На самом деле не совсем решил. Я обернул 2 интута в row и затем 2 по отдельности в  col- md- 6 (в общем как у вас показано). При этом они сейчас разошлись на большое расстояние( не как у меня на рисунке, второй верх. инпут вылезает далеко за нижний инпут).